# Stop UINavigationBar from applying blue background - iOS

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, background, uinavigationbar

I have an iOS application which uses a Navigation Bar with a custom background image. The problem is that although I set the buttons in the UINavigation bar to a plain background, they just remain as the default blue background. And so I get this unwanted and horrible effect:

[image]

How can I force Xcode to stop adding the annoying blue background to the buttons??

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Are you setting up the buttons in code or through Interface Builder / Storyboards?

Comment: @rmaddy I set up the buttons via Interface Builder in a Storyboard project.

Comment: @rmaddy But my UIView Controller has been embedded in another storyboard which has a UINavigationBar and hence this has inherited the UINavigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way. I'm not sure if this is the official way of doing it, but instead of adding a UINavigationBar Button, I just add a round rect button and set its background to clear. Then i added that to the UINavigationBar and it worked :)